# Cannot install npm packages in debian google cloud platform

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am trying to run my bot using google cloud and discord.js. But when I install npm packages it shows up with a lot of errors. I am a real newbie with google cloud and currently using debian 10 on GCP. Here is the error code. On internet I didn't find a possible solution.
I think the problem is with nodegit or node-pre-gyp. Can anyone help me pls?

```
npm WARN deprecated dblapi.js@2.4.1: Module is no longer maintained
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated snekfetch@4.0.4: use node-fetch instead
npm WARN deprecated canvas-constructor@3.2.0: Discontinued Support: please update to latest version
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.13.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
npm WARN deprecated discord.js@12.5.3: no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated node-opus@0.3.3: This project is unmaintained. See @discordjs/opus for an alternative.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/info/Fab/node_modules/nodegit
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node lifecycleScripts/preinstall && node lifecycleScripts/install
npm ERR! [nodegit] Running pre-install script
npm ERR! [nodegit] Running install script
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/home/info/Fab/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node --module_name=nodegit --module_path=/home/info/Fab/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp
npm ERR! info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp
npm ERR! info using node-pre-gyp@0.1.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using
npm ERR! node@16.11.1 | linux | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN
npm ERR! Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp
npm ERR! info check checked for "/home/info/Fab/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp
npm ERR! http GET https://axonodegit.s3.amazonaws.com/nodegit/nodegit/nodegit-v0.27.0-node-v93-linux-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp
npm ERR! http 404 https://axonodegit.s3.amazonaws.com/nodegit/nodegit/nodegit-v0.27.0-node-v93-linux-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp
npm ERR! WARN Tried to download(404): https://axonodegit.s3.amazonaws.com/nodegit/nodegit/nodegit-v0.27.0-node-v93-linux-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for nodegit@0.27.0 and node@16.11.1 (node-v93 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://axonodegit.s3.amazonaws.com/nodegit/nodegit/nodegit-v0.27.0-node-v93-linux-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp
npm ERR!
npm ERR! info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp
npm ERR! info using
npm ERR! node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp
npm ERR! info using
npm ERR! node@16.11.1 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp
npm ERR! info ok
npm ERR! gyp
npm ERR!
npm ERR! info
npm ERR!
npm ERR! it worked if it ends with
npm ERR! ok
npm ERR! gyp
npm ERR!
npm ERR! info
npm ERR!
npm ERR! using
npm ERR! node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp
npm ERR!
npm ERR! info
npm ERR!
npm ERR! using
npm ERR! node@16.11.1 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp
npm ERR! info find Python using Python version 3.7.3 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp
npm ERR! info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp
npm ERR! info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info
npm ERR! spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info
npm ERR! spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp
npm ERR! info spawn args   '/home/info/Fab/node_modules/nodegit/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info
npm ERR! spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp
npm ERR! info spawn args   '/root/.cache/node-gyp/16.11.1/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp
npm ERR! info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/root/.cache/node-gyp/16.11.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info
npm ERR! spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/root/.cache/node-gyp/16.11.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/info/Fab/node_modules/nodegit',
npm ERR! gyp
npm ERR! info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp
npm ERR! info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info
npm ERR! spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp
npm ERR! info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args
npm ERR! ]
npm ERR! /bin/sh: 1: krb5-config: not found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'krb5-config gssapi --libs' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:259:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.0-17-cloud-amd64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/info/Fab/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node" "--module_name=nodegit" "--module_path=/home/info/Fab/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/info/Fab/node_modules/nodegit
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.11.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/home/info/Fab/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node --module_name=nodegit --module_path=/home/info/Fab/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/info/Fab/node_modules/@discordjs/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:72:20)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.0-17-cloud-amd64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/info/Fab/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/info/Fab/node_modules/nodegit
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.11.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.1.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! [nodegit] ERROR - Could not finish install
npm ERR! [nodegit] ERROR - finished with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-12-07T16_43_17_819Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: try using a newer node-pre-gyp version

Comment: @MWO I tried but still the same error